# Узнать количество строк таблицы HTML для дальнейшей работы в php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть обычная таблица HTML с вложенными input. При клике на кнопку "Добавить строку", каждый раз создаётся ещё одна строка "tr". Необходимо узнать количество строк, после нажатия на кнопку "Оправить" или на какую-нибудь новую кнопку. И дальше работать с этим числом в коде php. Подсчитать строки в js не составляет труда. Но пока не понятно как передать это число в код php или подсчитать строки сразу в php.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вы же данные при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" куда-то отправляете? Вероятнее всего на бэк, т.е. в php. Туда же и отправить ещё одну переменную с числом строк. Если же данные отправляются массивом, то проще будет их на бэке и посчитать, не заморачиваясь с подсчетом средствами js.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь отправлять данные на бек?

Comment: изначально создаётся 4 строки tr посредством php. Затем при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить строку" добавляется ещё одна строка посредством js. Как эти строки посчитать на бэке не могу понять

Answer (score 1):

Все гораздо проще. Для этого вам нужно будет сформировать правильно форму. Ваша каждая строка из input должна быть примерно такой, где `[0]` это номер строки:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="array[0][title]">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="array[0][description]">
  </td>
</tr>
```

При передаче данных в в бэкенд в переменной $_POST будет следующее:

```
["array"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["description"]=>
      string(2) "11"
    }
  }
```

Для того чтобы получить количество строк в бэкенде, нужно будет сделать только `count($_POST['array'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы. Сделал немного по другому. Создал ещё 1 инпут в этой же форму. На js считаю количество строк и заношу это число в этот инпут при каждом клике. А потом через POST отправляю на сервер и дальше работаю с этим числом в php.

**admin.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="add.php">
    <table class="products__table">
        <tbody id="tblist">
            <tr>
                <td><input id="id" name="id[0] " value="1"></td>
                <td><input id="name" name="name[0]" type="text" value="ar11"></td>
                <td><input id="size" name="size[0]" value="123"></td>
                <td><input id="meters_tonne" name="meters_tonne[0]" value="111"></td>
                <td><input id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer[0]" value="uzb"></td>
                <td><input id="unit" name="unit[0]" value="tn"></td>
                <td><input id="price_transfer" name="price_transfer[0]" value="23525425"></td>
                <td><input id="price_cash" name="price_cash[0]" value="2523542"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="id" name="id[1] " value="2"></td>
                <td><input id="name" name="name[1]" type="text" value="ar22"></td>
                <td><input id="size" name="size[1]" value="234"></td>
                <td><input id="meters_tonne" name="meters_tonne[1]" value="222"></td>
                <td><input id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer[1]" value="ger"></td>
                <td><input id="unit" name="unit[1]" value="tn"></td>
                <td><input id="price_transfer" name="price_transfer[1]" value="523455452"></td>
                <td><input id="price_cash" name="price_cash[1]" value="15341234"></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr class="send_button_tr">
                <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Отправить"></td>
                <td><input id="hide_count_field" name="hide_field" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**admin.js**

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("tr").length - 1;
$('#hide_count_field').attr('value','' + matches + '');
```

**add.php**

```
$countOfStrokes = $_POST['hide_field'];
```